# Mongoose: Populated data fails in render to EJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

Dear StackOverflow users,

I encountered a problem when I was doing my project. To be simple, I'm using Mongoose to handle data between the server(Nodev8.9.1) and MongoDB(3.2.16-24), and the template engine is "EJS".

So far, I was able to populate two collections in the DB and if I use the find() method, it's returns the expected data by logging it to the console.
But whenever I try to render the same object with EJS, it's doesn't seems to be populated, only the populated field's key (e.g --> 0) value was returned. What could be the problem?

I know it's hard to imagine my trouble without a code sample, so I tried to paste the problematic piece of my codebase.

```
User.findById(req.user._id).
    populate('field').
    exec(function (err, user) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
      console.log(user.field); // => does it's job, returns all of my data inside array named "fields"
      res.render('rooms.ejs', { fields: user.field }); // => returns the key value of filed's keys
    });
```

While writing this "article", I was wondering if EJS supports to render the populated fields? (I can't find any article about this).

Thanks for your attention/help, have a nice day. :)

Comment: `person.field` or `user.field` ???

Comment: Thanks for the point. It was "user" originally, then I changed it to "person" because I was wondering it's getting into trouble by the req.user object. < It's not working in both way.